# Why does the last line in cmd powershell -command error

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

```
'C:\Users\kevin>powershell -Command "$Url = 'http://shared4.info/psequotes/files/2021/stockQuotes_$CurrentDate.csv'"

C:\Users\kevin>powershell -Command "$Path = 'C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\stockQuotes_$CurrentDate.csv'"

C:\Users\kevin>powershell -Command "$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient"

C:\Users\kevin>powershell -Command "$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $path)"
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull'
```

Comment: Settting the $Path variable needs to use QUOTATION MARK characters instead of APOSTROPHE characters in order to allow variable interpolation of $CurrentDate. Inside QUOTATION MARK characters, escape must be used. `"$Path = "C:\Users...otes_${CurrentDate}.csv\""`.

Comment: Also, it would probably be better to use `$Path = Join-Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "Desktop\stockQuotes_${CurrentDate}.csv\""`.

Answer (score 5):

You're starting a new Powershell session with each command.  And so the variable `$WebClient` doesn't exist in the powershell session created in the last command.

Instead of calling `powershell -Command`  on each line, call `powershell`  once and run all those statements in a single session. eg:

```
C:\Users\david>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\david> $Url = 'http://shared4.info/psequotes/files/2021/stockQuotes_$CurrentDate.csv'
PS C:\Users\david> $Path = 'C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\stockQuotes_$CurrentDate.csv'
PS C:\Users\david> $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
PS C:\Users\david> $WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

Or from a batch file like this:

```
powershell -Command ^
$Url = 'http://shared4.info/psequotes/files/2021/stockQuotes_$CurrentDate.csv'; ^
$Path = 'C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\stockQuotes_$CurrentDate.csv'; ^
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; ^
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $path);
```